# Z-index get overruled when there is an animation on parent element

Tags: css, css-animations

How can i properly fix this issue, so the blue layers overlaps the red elements on the next line.

Now the blue panels are below the red elements.

Tried various things:

```
transform-style: preserve-3d;
transform: translate3d(0,0,0); /*on all elements*/
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNbQre

Comment: Many CSS properties are known to cause issues with z-index stacking, including CSS transforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Z-indexes are always relative to their parent. So you can not set the z-index of the `.subpanel` elements above other `.item` elements, because the parents are not 'above' each other.

Read more about the stacking context here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

What you can do however, is give the `.item` elements a z-index, setting the 1st item highest etc... This can be easily achieved since you're using SCSS anyway.

I changed your for-loop in the SCSS

```
@for $i from 1 through 24 {
    .widthHelper:nth-child(#{$i}) .item {
        animation-delay: $i * 50ms;
        z-index: #{24 - $i + ($i % 4)};
    }
}
```

**Codepen:** http://codepen.io/grrtbrtr/pen/zveyBN

## Update

Updated the z-index calculation to allow overlap on both sides.
See [Codepen](http://codepen.io/grrtbrtr/pen/zveyBN) for more details.

This works if the elements grow to the left. If you want the `.subpanel` elements to overlap both left and right, you'll want to move them out of the `.item` elements, read up on the link above regarding z-index stacking context as to why this won't work when the overlapping elements are nested.

Comment: The problem is, that is shouldn't overlap, the previous elements too, if the subpanel is bigger then the element. updated the case, with your answer: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BoMvmg

Comment: Hey @woutvdd, I just updated my answer to accomplish this. The trick is in the z-index calculation.

You want the top right element to be the highest.

If you however, want the inner divs to overlap everything, you'll have to place them outside the `.item` elements I'm afraid.